# UIScrollView always snaps back to center

Tags: uiscrollview, swiftui

I have I vertical ScrollView in SwiftUI when I add "normal" Components then I can scroll normal but when I add a Component which gets the data from a websocket only the Content in the middle it is scrollable and the Content at the top and the bottom always snaps back to the middle

```
struct HomeView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var socketData: Socket
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                Text(String(socketData.message))
                LiveStats()
                LiveStats()
                LiveStats()
                LiveStats()
                LiveStats()
                Weather() //This is the View which gets the data async
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by applying a frame to the Weather struct but I don't know how to fix the problem when I don't have a certain height.

Comment: Weather() has a defined frame - inside. But Weather() gets too a frame from VStack. Thats the reason why it works with a additional frame-definition at Weather(). Thank you to answer your own question. It leads me to the correct solution on my problem.